# Okapi Java properties file and XLIFF file

Tags: xliff

Is it possible to use Okapi to convert java properties files to XLIFF and to reconstruct java properties file from XLIFF file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible using the [Properties Filter](https://okapiframework.org/wiki/index.php/Properties_Filter).

An example of doing this using Okapi Tikal would look like this:

```
tikal.sh -fc okf_properties -x sample.properties -nocopy
# translate the resulting sample.properties.xlf file
tikal.sh -fc okf_properties -m sample.properties.xlf
```

You can also use this with Rainbow as part of an extraction pipeline.